# Splitting on : with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file that contains data like this

```
word0:secondword0
word1:secondword1
word2:secondword2
word3:secondword3
word4:secon:word4
```

I'd like to use sed to split that content to give me only the second word after the first colon.

The end result would look like

```
secondword0
secondword1
secondword2
secondword3
secon:word4
```

Notice how the last word has a second colon that is part of the word.

How would I write such a script that splits on only the fist colon but retains the rest?

Comment: `sed 's/^[^:]*://' file`

Comment: This is completely trivial. What have you tried and how did it fail?

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following `sed` could help you in same.

```
sed 's/\([^:]*\):\(.*\)/\2/'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
secondword0
secondword1
secondword2
secondword3
secon:word4
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with gnu grep

```
grep -Po ':\K.*' <<END
word0:secondword0
word1:secondword1
word2:secondword2
word3:secondword3
word4:secon:word4
END
```

`:` matches the first occurence of `:` and `\K` keep `:` out of match `.*` matches the rest of the line, `-o` outputs only match

Comment: or `cut -d : -f 2 file` or `awk -F ':' '{print $2}' file`